# Javascript replace regex cuts result

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I've been trying for a while to solve something simple as replace sections of a long string with new content, but with a rather complex regular expression. The task is to replace hyperlinks within html supplied from elsewhere and pass them through a custom function before output.

```
function replaceHyperlinks(html){
    if(!source) return "";
    var str = source;

    // Modify <a> tag
    str = str.replace(/<a.*href="(.*?)".*>(.*?)<\/a>/gi, "<a onclick=\"javascript:openURL('$1')\" href=\"#\">$2</a>");
    return str;
}
```

The replacing seems to work in order. The problem is that it only does so for the first match, then it abruptly ends, also throwing away any remaining parts of the string after the first match.

I've looked around, but no one seems to have this problem what I can see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure to use the "?" on every single match, otherwise it'll greedily match everything.

```
/<a.*href="(.*?)".*>(.*?)<\/a>/gi
```

Having ".*" without a "?" will cause it to eat everything between the first and last instances of the pattern.

Take this:

```
<a href="/main">Main</a>  bunch of text or something <a href="/whatever">whatever</a>
```

Now, match it with that expression, adding parentheses shows what matches:

```
text = '<a href="/main">Main</a>  bunch of text or something <a href="/whatever">whatever</a>'
text.match(/<a(.*)href="(.*?)"(.*)>(.*?)<\/a>/i)
[
 "<a href="/main">Main</a>  bunch of text or something <a href="/whatever">whatever</a>",
 " href="/main">Main</a>  bunch of text or something <a ",
 "/whatever",
 "",
 "whatever"
]
```

Ignore the first item in the array, as it's the entire match.  The second item is the match from the first set of parents, and you can see it's grabbing too much.

```
text.match(/<a(.*?)href="(.*?)"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/i)
["<a href="/main">Main</a>", " ", "/main", "", "Main"]
```

That's what you want to match.